# How to save an image in django in a folder named with the object id?

Tags: django

I have a django backend with this:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
def portada_inmueble_path(instance, file_name):
    print('ID', instance.pk) // Here the id or pk is None
    return '{}/{}/{}'.format(
        instance.inmobiliaria.id,
        instance.pk,
        file_name)


class Inmueble(models.Model):
...
portada = models.ImageField(upload_to=portada_inmueble_path, blank=True,
                                null=True, max_length=99)
...
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Inmueble)
def inmueble_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    new_file = instance.portada
    try:
        old_file = Inmueble.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).portada
        if not old_file == new_file:
            if os.path.isfile(old_file.path):
                os.remove(old_file.path)
    except:
        pass
```

I need to name the file path like this:

```
/media/inmobiliaria_id/inmueble_id/portada.jpg
```

My problem is that the id of the inmueble (property) does not exist in the path because it was not created yet. How do I get the id and create the folder with that name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the ID before saving it as you mentioned because the ID will be generated by database and you have no control over it.

Some options:

- First do your saving without an image and then get the id, make the directory and then add the image and update the row.

(Fast, Clean, Not much code needed. Might some problems happen before adding the image (Like server crash which is rare but still it might happen.)

- Save everything and then change the image location.

(It's basically like the first option but the other way around. More code needed, Need to work with files. Still there might be problems like server crash)

- You can create a custom unique ID and generate it while you'r saving and use that as the ID for the path.

(Best option in my opinion, Not much code needed (just check if the generated id already exist or not). Pretty clean, Does everything once without any updates needed and you won't run to a problem such as server crash.

Comment: Thanks, If my choice is the first option, can i do it in a post_save method? and how? can u give me an example?

Comment: simply save everything but the image, and then update the same row with the image. you should do it in your template. or override the form save method.